# How to save elasticsearch date type in spring data?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to use spring data to get elasticsearch documents, but encountered some problems with get data.
Here is my code.
Entity:

```
@Id
private String id;

@Field(name = "@timestamp", type = FieldType.Date)
private Date timestamp;

@Field(name = "netflow.first_switched", type = FieldType.Date)
private Date firstSwitched;

@Field(name = "netflow.last_switched", type = FieldType.Date)
private Date lastSwitched;
```

My data in elasticsearch:
[image]

I want to test spring data can get document or not(implement ElasticsearchRepository), so I hard code ID like:

```
Optional<OriginalData> a = originalDataService.findById("nfQ8KHMBB49SfiIiH2rK");
```

And then I got an exception:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Date] for value '2020-07-07T07:44:54.878Z'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

so I modify my Entity code to

```
    @Id
    private String id;

//    @Field(name = "@timestamp", type = FieldType.Date)
//    private Date timestamp;

    @Field(name = "netflow.first_switched", type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
    private LocalDateTime firstSwitched;

    @Field(name = "netflow.last_switched", type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
    private LocalDateTime lastSwitched;
```

still wrong, but got another exception:

```
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.ConversionException: could not create object of class java.time.LocalDateTime
```

My questions are:

1. How to use spring data get elasticsearch document with field containing data type?
2. I want to get field "@timestamp", can I get this?

Does anyone can help me, please?

Kase

Comment: Which versions of Elasticsearch and Spring Data Elasticsearch do you use? And what is the mapping of the index in Elasticsearch, how are these time fields defined?

Comment: Hi, My Elasticsearch version:7.8, Spring Data Elasticsearch:4.0.0.RELEASE
And what is the mapping of the index in Elasticsearch, how are these time fields defined? ->I'm not sure if you mean that or not...thest documents came from logstash, I used logstash netflow plugin to help me trans netflow data.

Comment: I have tried this at kibana dev tools:
`GET elastiflow-3.5.3-2020.06.24/_mapping/field/netflow.first_switched`
and I get this

{
  "elastiflow-3.5.3-2020.06.24" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "netflow.first_switched" : {
        "full_name" : "netflow.first_switched",
        "mapping" : {
          "first_switched" : {
            "type" : "date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: I also tried 
GET /elastiflow-3.5.3-2020.07.07/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": [ "nfQ8KHMBB49SfiIiH2rK" ] 
    }
  }
}
And it can get 1 document.

Comment: As for the Date-Format, two short remarks: 
- You are using yyyy for the Year. As of Elasticseach 7 you should use uuuu instead (mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model.annotations) )
- If that does not help, try using a predefined format instead of custom, i.e. DateFormat.basic_date_time